# Accessing state variable in SwiftUI View outside the body

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a content view and I want to track dynamically the height.

I have implemented this solution but i encounter this Exception :

> Fatal error: Accessing State outside View.body: file

What can i do to have keyboardHeight dynamic which can update my UI

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)
        .merge(with: NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification))
        .compactMap({ notification in
          guard let keyboardFrameValue: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return nil }
          let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
          if keyboardFrame.origin.y == UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
            return 0
          } else {
            return keyboardFrame.height - (UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0)
          }
        })
        .assign(to: \.keyboardHeight, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment.bottom) {
                List {
                    Text("Default text").foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
                TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant(""))
                    .frame(minHeight: 30)
                    .cornerRadius(8.0)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: keyboardHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create the publisher as a private property (without the `assignTo`), and subscribe to it in the view body using `onReceive`. I believe this will give you what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is pretty much saying exactly what the problem is. However, although you cannot access State variables outside the body function (or a function called from body), you can access observable objects. So simply changing @State by @ObservedObject and defining a tiny class, is enough to make it work.

Note that this solution is to keep your workflow idea intact. Although, there're other ways to accomplish the same thing.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)
            .merge(with: NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification))
            .compactMap({ notification in
                guard let keyboardFrameValue: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return nil }

                let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue

                if keyboardFrame.origin.y == UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return keyboardFrame.height - (UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0)
                }
            })
            .assign(to: \.keyboardHeight, on: model)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment.bottom) {
                List {
                    Text("Default text").foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
                TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant(""))
                    .frame(minHeight: 30)
                    .cornerRadius(8.0)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: model.keyboardHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Other ways to do the same thing? Yes, but is there something wrong with this way?

Comment: Do you have to create a tiny class because a `CGFloat` can not be a `ObservableObject`?